# Currie mid-drive Pedal assist works sporadically

Tags: mountain-bike, electric-bike

I have a Raleigh Route with a Curry Electro Drive trans x 350 watt pedal. Assist only motor. Pedal assist starts and stops almost immediately over and over the entire time I ride. Sometimes it doesn't work at all. I've opened it up and checked connections and everything seems to be fine but it looks like I have to completely take it apart to get to the pedal assist sensor. Not sure if it's even that. Is there anyone that could possibly help me with this? I'm not sure if I can even get parts for this thing. Maybe pedal assist sensor from another motor could work. Please help. Thank you.